# CRUD Delete salesforce security issue

Tags: salesforce, checkmarx

when received a scan results how salesforce-Checkmarx will do code scan, so my question is, as per some blogs and salesforce standard documentation I checked delete permission before deleting a record, but still I am getting CURD Delete Issue, (security submission done 2 time, got same results). I am specifying a my code

```
            if(Schema.SobjectType.Tracking_path__c.isdeletable())
            {
                Delete tpList;
            }    
            else
            {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new  ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL, system.label.delete_access)); 
                return null; 
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Got the fix for this issue. If you change your code like below you will get it fixed in review report.

```
List<CustomObject__c> listOfCustomObject = [Select Fields from CustomObject__c];
if(CustomObject__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isDeletable()){
    delete listOfCustomObject;
 }
```